# Define tcolorbox in math mode

Tags: math-mode, tcolorbox

Since in my document I have to write a lot of math in colored box, I'd like to avoid to write $ inside every box. Is there a way to define `newtcbox` in math mode?

I tried with `\newtcbox{\mywbox}[1]{<options>}{$\displaystyle #1$}` but it doesn't work.

This is my latex code:

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\mywbox}{on line,colback=white,colframe=black,size=fbox,arc=3pt,boxrule=0.8pt}

\begin{document}
\obeylines

This \mywbox{$3x$} is in line math.
This $$y=\mywbox{$-5x$}-5+6$$ is not in line math.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I read about `\tcboxmath` and `\tcbhighmath` in the official tcolorbox manual, but I don't understand how to define them simply as the newtcbox and if they are what I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say

```latex
\newtcbox{\mywboxtext}{on line,colback=white,colframe=black,size=fbox,arc=3pt,boxrule=0.8pt}
\newcommand{\mywboxmath}[1]{\mywboxtext{$#1$}}
```

Your example can become

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\mywboxtext}{on line,colback=white,colframe=black,size=fbox,arc=3pt,boxrule=0.8pt}
\newcommand{\mywboxmath}[1]{\mywboxtext{$#1$}}

\begin{document}

This \mywboxmath{3x} is in line math and this
\[
y=\mywboxmath{-5x}-5+6
\]
is display math.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Change the names to your liking.

[Avoid `$$` in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503) (and of course also `\obeylines`).

Should you need the boxes to behave in subscripts or superscripts, change the code into

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\mywboxtext}{on line,colback=white,colframe=black,size=fbox,arc=3pt,boxrule=0.8pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mywboxmath}[1]{\mathpalette\mywboxmath@do{#1}}
\newcommand{\mywboxmath@do}[2]{\mywboxtext{$\m@th#1#2$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This $\mywboxmath{3x}$ is in line math and this
\[
y_{\mywboxmath{0}}=\mywboxmath{-5x}-5+6
\]
is display math.

\end{document}
```

Note that in this case you need that `\mywboxmath` is in math mode.

Answer (score 12):

You can do this using `\tcboxmath` from the `theorems` library of `tcolorbox`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newcommand*{\mywbox}{%
  \tcboxmath[colback=white, colframe=black, size=fbox, arc=3pt, boxrule=0.8pt]%
}

\begin{document}

This \mywbox{3x} is in line math.
This
\[ y = \mywbox{-5x} - 5 + 6 \]
is not in line math.

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

You may want to abstract things a little bit using a style too, so that you can apply it to other boxes should the need arise:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\tcbset{my math box/.style={
          colback=white, colframe=black, size=fbox, arc=3pt, boxrule=0.8pt}
}

\newcommand*{\mywbox}{\tcboxmath[my math box]}

\begin{document}

This \mywbox{3x} is in line math.
This
\[ y = \mywbox{-5x} - 5 + 6 \]
is not in line math.

\end{document}
```

## Making the background of the box transparent

This can be done using `/tcb/opacityback` and a skin using a *jigsaw* frame engine, such as `standard jigsaw` or `enhanced jigsaw`.

```latex
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\tcbset{
  my math box/.style={
    standard jigsaw,   % useful for 'opacityback' and 'opacityframe'
    colback=green!20, colframe=black, size=fbox, arc=3pt, boxrule=0.8pt,
    opacityback=0.6,
  }
}

\newcommand*{\mywbox}{\tcboxmath[my math box]}

\begin{document}

This \makebox[0pt]{%
  \raisebox{-0.5\height}[0pt][0pt]{\hspace{1cm}\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}%
  }%
\mywbox{3x} is in line math.
This
\[ y = \mywbox{-5x} - 5 + 6 \]
is not in line math.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make the back of the layer/box transparent respectively lower the opacity?

Comment: @Leon I've added an example of this to my answer.